# Designing class methods: self contained or explicit calls?

Tags: coding-style, class-design

I'm probably butchering the terms, if someone knows the appropriate terms - that'd be great.

But my question is: should I design my classes so that their methods' parameters be accessible from the outside, or should they be all self contained?

For example, I want to set a domain name for a class, which will served as the 'active' domain:

```
function setDomain($url){
        if ($this -> domainUrl = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST)){
            $this-> domain = $this->db->get_where('domains', array('host' => $this->domainUrl));

            return $this;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

and then go the route of:

```
function addDomain(){
        $query = "INSERT INTO domains (host) VALUES ('$this->domainUrl')";
        $this->db->query($query);
        return $this
    }
```

or I can abandon the entire route of setDomain(), and than just call the url explicitly, such as:

```
function addDomain($url){
        $query = "INSERT INTO domains (host) VALUES ('$url')";
        $this->db->query($query);
    }
```

Which would you say is preferable and I guess - what is that dependent upon, because there might be cases where I'll need to call it explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally only set attributes on the instance if:

- you will be making many calls with those exact arguments,
- the parameters need to be collected from various places for final processing, or
- there is so many arguments that you need to name them.

Otherwise passing an argument is less code and less code is more readable. Also the compiler/interpreter will tell you when you missed argument, while you have to check yourself when you forgot to call a setter.

Answer (score 1):

As with any general design question, the answer to this question is also **it depends.** It all depends on your *abstraction* for the class.

Let me give two examples that illustrate two different abstractions:

`class DomainOperator`: This highly fictitious class takes care of performing various operations on a domain. Given a domain, it can store it, make some String-relevant operations on it, etc... For this class, I would go declaring the `domainURL` as an instance variable. Multiple methods should be making use of it; it acts as a global within a class.

`class WebSite`: Yet another made-up class that is responsible for storing the properties of a web-site; domain is one of these properties. It has a method called `addDomain(url)` and in this method, it stores the domain.

I am not too happy with these examples, but the point is that it depends on what you want to do with your class. If your class logic is based on a domain, then I would make it an instance variable. If not, a parameter would be fine.

Side note: These small decisions become easier with refactoring. If you look at a class and you see 4 methods (out of 7) using a variable, then it might be time to extract these 4 methods out into a new class; making the shared variable an instance variable of the new class.